# How to solve $x^x=2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve it using the super logarithm and tetration and I've gotten to $\operatorname{sexpx}(\operatorname{sexpx}(2))=\operatorname{sexpx}(\operatorname{slogx}(2x)x)$, and due to the lack of general product/sum rules for tetration in my bit of research I can't think of any way to simplify it further, and I can't find any alternative method so I'm completely lost.

Comment: You could try numerical means, such as Newton-Raphson's Method

Comment: One answer is $x=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you work in the real domain, $x$ must be positive.

Now, consider the function $$f(x)=x^x-2x$$ and its derivatives $$f'(x)=x^x (\log (x)+1)-2$$  $$f''(x)=x^{x-1}+x^x (\log (x)+1)^2$$ Solving $f'(x)=0$ does not seem to be feasible but the second derivative is always positive.

We can also notice that $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=-1$ ($x=2$ being a trivial solution and $f''(x)>0$ implies two roots). So, there is one real root between $0$ and $1$ and a numerical method such as Newton will find it. Starting using $x_0=\frac 12$, the successive iterates would be $$x_1=0.3357321609$$ $$x_2=0.3462677112$$ $$x_3=0.3463233608$$ $$x_4=0.3463233623$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note that your equation is equivalent to
$$(x-1)\log x = \log 2.$$

Identify the obvious solution, then prove that the LHS is monotonic for $0 < x < 1$ and $x>1$.

There will be a second solution in $(0,1)$, but I don't see any hope of it having a closed form.

Comment: Is it obvious the equation has no solutions for negative $x$?

Comment: @Lythia Fair enough; I assumed the domain was $x>0$ but if you allow negative $x$ you also need to check that $x^{x-1} \neq 2$ for $x$ a negative integer, which is straightforward.

Comment: Why just an integer? For instance what about $x=-\tfrac{3}{5}$? This is not a solution, but it's not too far away either.

Comment: @Lythia How are you defining $x^x$? The principal value is not real for $x=-3/5$.

Comment: I'm somewhat trolling here, but naively I can plug in $-\tfrac{3}{5}$ into my calculator and it will give me an answer to $$(-\frac{3}{5})^{-3/5}$$.

Comment: @Lythia Well I just typed it into Google and got $-0.419847541 - 1.29215786 i$... ;)

Comment: powers don't need to be integers.  p^m/n is the n-th root of p^m.  x^x for x = -3/5 is okay because it's the 5th root of -27/125.  But -3/4 is not because that would be the 4th root of -27/64 which is invalid on your calculator (but acceptable with complex numbers).  if the base is positive b^x is defined for all real x by taking limits.